# import-csv, get-aduser, then export-csv to filter out non-existing AD users

Tags: csv, powershell

```
Import-Csv C:\username.csv | 
ForEach-Object (Get-ADUser $_.Username -Properties displayname | 
Export-Csv C:\usernames.csv
```

I have an old fileserver (2k3) with a bunch of homefolders.  I exported a csv with `get-childitem` for the directories.  I was going to use the name of the folder, which is mirrored to the AD username, to query AD with `Get-ADUser`.  If AD user does not exist, then filter out those non existing users and `export-csv` the "active" ad users. The exported CSV would then be used in my script to migrate "active" homefolders to new homefolder VM.  I have used the above code unsuccessfully.  Any input would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

briantist is correct about the curly braces.

To expand a little on his answer, you want to also include the -NoType parameter to the Export-CSV statement so the resulting CSV doesn't have a type line at the top. This makes it easier to manipulate with Excel and to feed into other PowerShell scripts!

I've put it all together for you in a single line.

```
Import-Csv C:\username.csv | ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser $_.Username -Properties displayname} | Export-Csv C:\usernames.csv -Notype
```

This tested as expected in my test lab with Windows 2012 R2.

One additional question: If your goal is to get a list of "active" AD users so you only migrate needed folders, then do you want all the info from the export? It sounds like you just need the username. Let me know and I can adjust the code for you.

**EDIT:**
Here is the revised code to just get the list of usernames that are valid from a the CSV file as an import. I've also included code to use just a list of usernames as input in case you end up using that.

With the original CSV file as input:

```
Import-CSV C:\username.csv | ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser $_.username -Properties *} | select -expand SAMAccountName | Out-File C:\usernames.txt
```

With just a list of usernames as input:

```
Get-Content C:\username.txt | ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser $_ -Properties *} | select -expand SAMAccountName | Out-File C:\usernames.txt
```

Notice the distinction in the $_ pipeline input. One calls for a property (because it is an array of properties) and the other just calls for the whole variable (because it is a single entry).

Anyway, hope that helps!

Comment: Wow nice, thanks McKenning.  Correct I have just the Username column that only concerns me.  If you want to modify it for just the "username" column that would be helpful.  I have the other LastWrite and LastAccess properties as well just in case I need it.  I appreciate your input McKenning.  The code looks correct though.  I will test asap in the morning.

Comment: This worked McKenning.  I tested first thing this morning and it worked beautifully.  Now on to my next phase of the copy-item for the homefolders :) Thanks Brian and McK.

Answer (score 3):

I've reformatted your code a bit, without changing the meaning. I think you may have copy/pasted incorrectly.

`ForEach-Object` takes a `[ScriptBlock]` (denoted by curly braces `{ }`):

You have used a parenthesis `(` without a closing one `)`.

You should have:

```
ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser $_.Username -Properties displayname }
```

Comment: So you think this will accomplish my desired csv data?

Comment: @TheJanitor to be honest I'm not certain, I answered this pretty quickly once I saw the syntax error. It looks like [the answer from McKenning](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33771085/3905079) better researches your end goal.